# Example of a countably additive function which is not a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there a simple example showing that a non-negative countably additive function on a $\sigma$-algebra fails to be a measure?

Comment: Do you want a [complex measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure)? Every positive $\sigma$-additive function is a measure.

Comment: @HanulJeon Not true. There's exactly one counterexample for a given sigma-algebra...

Comment: @HanulJeon Also btw it _is_ true that every countably additive complex-valued function _is_ a complex measure.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I did not realize there is the counterexample. I have learnt a measure as non-negative $\sigma$-additive function, but I confirm that the text I have been used excludes trivial one, by assuming there is some $A$ such that $f(A) < \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a *wrong* proof that if $\mathcal A$ is a sigma-algebra then any countably additive $\mu:\mathcal A\to[0,\infty]$ is a measure. Locating the error will lead you to the example you want:

By definition, we need only show that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. Say $m=\mu(\emptyset)$. Since $\mu$ is countably additive we have $m=m+m+m+\dots$. Hence $m=0$.

Comment: You assumed that $\mu(\emptyset)$ is some finite $m$ and that is the problem here? $\mu(\emptyset)$ might be not finite a priori...

Comment: @luka5z I don't recall assuming that, no.

Comment: @luka5z But of course that's just quibbling; yes, the point is that $\mu(\emptyset)$ may be infinite.

Comment: the only countably additive function on a $\sigma$-algebra which is not a measure is the countably additive function whose value at every subset of the $\sigma$-algebra is infinity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Just used the wrong word. BTW very nice answer. I would upvote it 10 times if I could.